# PHP While loop to increment variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have this php code. Everything is going well until the $insert. What I want to get are different variables during the loop.

For example, the first loop it should get

$A1

The next loop is to get $A2 and so on. I'm doing this because after I've finished all of this, the variables are going to be over a hundred.

What I thought would work is to make something like

```
$b='$A';
```

But clearly it's not working.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$A1=$_POST['a1'];
$A2=$_POST['a2'];
$A3=$_POST['a3'];
$examinee=$_POST['examinee'];
$Q1=$_POST['q1'];
echo $A1 . '<BR>'
    . $A2 . '<BR>'
    . $A3 . '<BR>'
    . $examinee . '<BR>'
    . $Q1;

$query = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$examinee'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
    echo "Table exists";
}
else {
    $create="CREATE TABLE $examinee (ano int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, answer varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (ano))";
    $conn->query($create);


    $a=1;
    $b='$A';

    while ($a<4) {
        $insert="INSERT INTO $examinee (ano, answer) VALUES ('', '$b.$a')";
        $conn->query($insert);
        $a++;
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to happen is for the values of the variables $A1, $A2, $A3 to be inserted in the database using the while loop.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: why are you not just using a db auto incremented id?

Comment: I don't know how is this unclear but again, as everyone can see, in line 3 there's a $A1=$_POST['a1'];. So in the while loop containing the $insert, I want the value of $A1, $A2 and so on to be inserted to the database with every loop. In short, I want to put $A1 in the VALUES but how do i increment it every loop.

Comment: This database design is so wrong - 1 database with 1 table with 1 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I agree with Ed Cottrell here in that you are wide open to SQL injection, but given the current implementation, I think you could use an array to do what you want much faster.  See section of code below.

```
<?php
$post_array = array(
    $_POST['a1'],
    $_POST['a2'],
    $_POST['a3']
);

// printout statements and database connection here as above

for ($i = 0; $i < count($post_array); $i++) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO $examinee (ano, answer) VALUES ('', " . $post_array[$i] . ")";
    $conn->query($insert);
}
```

A much better implementation would use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: While we're not using prepared statements, you might as well just use $_POST array in the loop instead of making another array. And atleast throw a [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) around the variable while you're at it. `$conn->real_esacape_string($_POST['a'.$i])`

Comment: I will try to address the SQL injection thing at a later time. I'm sure it's pretty easy to search for solutions in here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to insert the value stored in $A1, $A2, $A3, $A4 into a string, doing something like:

```
<?php

$A1 = 'some';
$A2 = 'set';
$A3 = 'of';
$A4 = 'inputs';

for ($a = 1; $a <= 4 ; $a++) {
  echo ${"A".$a};
}
?>
```

so in your case, it would be something like:

```
$insert="INSERT INTO $examinee (ano, answer) VALUES ('', '" . ${"A" . $a} .  "')";
```

It's not the route I would go though... because I dislike [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)